# Ограничение MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть поле "процент надбавки" - "percentage of allowances"

`percentage of allowances` int not null, -- поле из таблицы

constraint chk_Percentage1 check(`percentage of allowances` >= 0 and `percentage of allowances` <= 100) -- ограничение

Почему, имея это ограничения, я все равно могу вписывать значение больше 100 и меньше нуля?

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, потому, что, согласно документации

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

Comment: и как тогда добавить адекватное ограничение?

Comment: Вариантов несколько Можно трансформировать тип поля в ENUM с соотв. набором допустимых значений, если их количество не превышает 64к-1. Можно ввести ограничения триггерной логикой. Можно вставку и изменение данных выполнять в рамках ХП, где выполнять соотв. контроль.

Comment: да господи, мне просто чек от 0 до 100. всё. Как в SQL. Только в SQL ограничение соблюдается а в mysql - нет.

Comment: От 0 до 100 и только целые? тогда ENUM, и задача решена.

Comment: @Kryshtop Или триггер. по другому - никак. Хотя есть хороший выход - использовать более адекватные СУБД

Comment: например как MS SQL Server, согласен :3